# How to make book cover shadow like below

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, calayer

[image]

i need right left and bottom shadow on `UIImageView` not below tried below code for shadow but not working as expected

```
viewCheck.layer.shadowRadius  = 1.5f;
viewCheck.layer.shadowColor   = [UIColor colorWithRed:176.f/255.f green:199.f/255.f blue:226.f/255.f alpha:1.f].CGColor;
viewCheck.layer.shadowOffset  = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
viewCheck.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9f;
viewCheck.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

UIEdgeInsets shadowInsets     = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -1.5f, 0);
UIBezierPath *shadowPath      = [UIBezierPath 
bezierPathWithRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(viewCheck.bounds, shadowInsets)];
viewCheck.layer.shadowPath    = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

Comment: shadow will work only on UIView. so add a uiview below imageview and make shadow for the uiview

Comment: If you change your insets to this: `UIEdgeInsets shadowInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.5f, -1.5f, -1.5f, -1.5f);` does it give you what you want? Or, are you trying to give it a "beveled plus partial drop-shadow" look?

Comment: @FahimParkar -- Hmm???? Shadows work fine on `UIImageView`...